Restore deleted package on Azure Devops Artifact Feed
We have an Azure Devops Artifact Feed, with NuGet as an upstream source.
Somehow, I don't believe we have actually deleted them but we have some deleted packages that we are unable to restore. As you can see below (Searched on the Upstream Source), there are several packages 2.0.0- 2.1.2 that are marked as deleted. All of these other versions I am not sure where they have come from as they are not available talking straight to a plain NuGet feed. These other versions, which are in fact much older that begin 2011 etc, are part of the problem I think. I manually deleted the 2011.13.4094.
But I need this 2.1.2 version which is an external source. There is nothing in the recycle bin etc, I believe this happened a long time ago.


If you observed the 2.1.2 version of the oxyplot.wpf was Deleted from this feed but it was invisible in the Package Recycle Bin, it was probably permanently deleted from this feed already.

Additionally, I am afraid that we are unable to recover it back into this feed, which was by-design to ensure the correctness of the build results.
Referencing the document on Key concepts for Azure Artifacts - Immutability, if you have to use this specific version of the package,

The only way to work around the immutability constraint is to create a new feed and publish the desired package version to the new feed.

